# Android social network app data storage

Tags: android

I'm developing an app in android(Social Network). I need to save following user data on client side after login:
1-FirstName,LastName,Education,Sex,Languages and some other 20 Strings.
2-I need two arraylists of 15 size, and every node contains 3 strings(Title,Descrition etc)
3-Encoded Image string.
4-some boolean settings.

I'm using PHP as backend server and JSON as data transfer language.
Please guide me how to store all this data????

Comment: You should firstly learn fundamentals of android programming. As for solution, you can use SharedPreferences to store user data.

Comment: I know  about SharedPreferences, but it can be used only for primitive datatypes.

Comment: You can save your large strings (such as encoded image string) into a text files separately and save their path to SharedPreferences.